# Reload .vimrc in Vim without restart

Tags: vim

It bothers me when I wrote something into `.vimrc` and I have to close it first and open to get my changes be applied. 
Is there a way of reload `.vimrc` in Vim without closing it?

E.g. I've added `set nu` to `~/.vimrc` and I want line numbers to appear for all my windows and buffers.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

`:source ~/.vimrc`

Run that from inside vim, that will apply your `.vimrc`

Alternately

`:source $MYVIMRC`

Answer (score 28):

`:so %`

if currently editing .vimrc

Comment: i.e. `:source %`

Comment: Underrated answer.  Fewer keystrokes; this is prob the one I'll remember

Answer (score 22):

Here's one for posterity. Add the following to your .vimrc:

```
map <leader>vimrc :tabe ~/.vim/.vimrc<cr>
autocmd bufwritepost .vimrc source $MYVIMRC
```

The first line means you can open your vimrc from any vim buffer by typing your leader, then writing "vimrc." For example, my leader is set to comma, so if I'm in edit mode and I type ",vimrc" it opens my vimrc in a new tab.

The second line automatically sources the changes to your vimrc when you save and close it. It's magic.

Comment: Ideally wouldnt you `map <leader>vimrc :tabe $MYVIMRC<cr>` to match the autocmd?

Comment: @NickBisby For me `~/.vimrc` is just a stub that sources `~/.vim/.vimrc` so that I can keep everything under source control. For most people you are correct, it would be `:tabe $MYVIMRC<cr>`.

Comment: Alternatively you could use a symbolic link to your actual .vimrc file instead of having it be a stub.

Comment: How can I reload vimrc without changing the position of my cursor?

Comment: The `autocmd` is going to register a new additional autocmd every time you source the vimrc

Answer (score 4):

```
" Quickly edit/reload this configuration file
nnoremap gev :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
nnoremap gsv :so $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

To **automatically** reload upon save, add the following to your `$MYVIMRC`:

```
if has ('autocmd') " Remain compatible with earlier versions
 augroup vimrc     " Source vim configuration upon save
    autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source % | echom "Reloaded " . $MYVIMRC | redraw
    autocmd! BufWritePost $MYGVIMRC if has('gui_running') | so % | echom "Reloaded " . $MYGVIMRC | endif | redraw
  augroup END
endif " has autocmd
```

and then for the last time, type:

```
:so %
```

The next time you save your `vimrc`, it will be automatically reloaded.

**Features:**

- Tells the user what has happened (also logging to `:messages`)
- Handles various names for the configuration files
- Ensures that it wil only match the actual configuration file (ignores copies in other directories, or a `fugitive://` diff)
- Won't generate an error if using `vim-tiny`

Of course, the automatic reload will only happen if you edit your `vimrc` in vim.

Comment: This is great, but when I have the window maximized (gvim), it resizes it to a windowed state. Any idea how to solve that?